# Send Sip Message through fastagi asterisk

Tags: asterisk, agi, fastagi

I am able to relay messages using dialplan. This command sends the message but I cant seem to run it using fastagi(java)

**DialPlan**

```
exten => _X.,n,MessageSend(${ACTUALTO},${MESSAGE(from)})
```

**FastAgi**

```
public void service(AgiRequest ar, AgiChannel ac) throws AgiException {
    System.out.println(ac.getFullVariable("${MESSAGE(body)}"));
    System.out.println(ac.getFullVariable("${MESSAGE(to)}"));
    System.out.println(ac.getFullVariable("${MESSAGE(from)}"));
    System.out.println(ac.getFullVariable("${CUT(MESSAGE(to),@,1)}"));
    //Correct values are show from above printlns
    ac.exec("MessageSend(${CUT(MESSAGE(to),@,1)},${MESSAGE(from)})");
}
```

Last line results in a warning in `/var/asterisk/messages`

> WARNING[2287][C-00000000] res_agi.c: Could not find application (MessageSend(${CUT(MESSAGE(to),@,1)})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, this is how it is done in fastagi

```
ac.exec("MessageSend","sip:100,<sip:102@192.168.1.100:5080>");
```

Documentation for MessageSend 
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_MessageSend

Answer (score 0):

So far message is expected. There are no **AGI** command like that

Check

asterisk -rx "core show application like message"

if found, try do

```
 ac.exec("MessageSend \"${CUT(MESSAGE(to),@,1)},${MESSAGE(from)})\"");
```

For more info check specification

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/exec